# SAP WSDL's being generated incomplete

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, netweaver

I recently tried to create a basic Hello World web service (through the Function Builder), and turn it into a WSDL. Then using (Java) wsimport function turning it into java files.

The function looks like this:

```
FUNCTION ZWEBSERVICE1.
  write: / 'hello world'.
ENDFUNCTION.
```

The first problem I encountered is while executing wsimport. I got a error that states that wsdl:service is not in the file. After googling a while, I found no discussions/solutions to that problem. So I just wrote:

```
  <wsdl:service name="ZWEBSERVICE1">

  </wsdl:service>
```

into the file, and executed wsimport  again, and got my .java and .class files.

The next problem I encountered is that the ZWEBSERVICE1.java class is somewhat empty... It looks like this:

```
...
public class ZWEBSERVICE1 {

}
```

...  so now I am at my wits end, and hope that someone can give me some insight in what I did wrong.

I posted this as discussion on SAP, so if there are any changes there I will update this topic: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3800470

Answer (score 0):

`WRITE` is used to produce ABAP lists for interactive display of offline usage within the ABAP system. It is not suitable for web services in any way. Since your function does not appear to have any parameters, it doesn't make much sense to turn it into a web service - I wouldn't expect anything but an empty WSDL file in this case...

Comment: Okay, makes sense. So I just found out that the way to pass parameters is if you set the tick on pass value... so I attempted to make a WSDL out of a C= A+B. service. Here I do get ability to actualy call the adition. I think that I missunderstood some basics of how all this works. Is there any good guide or documentaton that you can suggest?

Comment: I don't know (I'm not a WS expert), and apart from that, asking for external documentation is off-topic here :-)